# Composite of two simple extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $a, b$ be algebraic elements over a field $K$ and suppose at least one of
these two elements is separable over $K$. Then, prove that there exists $c$
such that $K(a, b) = K(c)$.